# How to format the way provider resources get generated with Crossplane?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubebuilder, crossplane

Im looking to build a crossplane provider for my organization however im running to issues with the code generation.

Is there a way to manipulate how the resource names get generated? The Upjet code generations tools do not seem to respect the naming format for certain resources.

for example:

We have a terraform resource with this format.
`provider_load_balancer` after adding the resource and running `make generate`
the resource gets generated. However, the following gets generated.

```
├── apis
│   ├── generate.go
│   ├── load
│   │   └── v1alpha1
│   │       ├── zz_balancer_types.go
│   │       ├── zz_generated.deepcopy.go
│   │       ├── zz_generated.managed.go
│   │       ├── zz_generated.managedlist.go
│   │       ├── zz_generated_terraformed.go
│   │       └── zz_groupversion_info.go

├── examples-generated
│   ├── load
│   │   └── balancer.yaml
```

The CRDS, yamls and file structure get generated incorrectly. Ideally, the directories and CRDS should not split the resource name but rather have them as one string `loadbalancer`

Below we see even the deepcopy methods get generated with the wrong name. These Should be `loadbalancer` not `balancer`

```
// DeepCopyInto is an autogenerated deepcopy function, copying the receiver, writing into out. in must be non-nil.
func (in *Balancer) DeepCopyInto(out *Balancer) {
    *out = *in
    out.TypeMeta = in.TypeMeta
    in.ObjectMeta.DeepCopyInto(&out.ObjectMeta)
    in.Spec.DeepCopyInto(&out.Spec)
    in.Status.DeepCopyInto(&out.Status)
}

// DeepCopy is an autogenerated deepcopy function, copying the receiver, creating a new Balancer.
func (in *Balancer) DeepCopy() *Balancer {
    if in == nil {
        return nil
    }
    out := new(Balancer)
    in.DeepCopyInto(out)
    return out
}
```

Any ideas about what I can do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the group for an individual generated resource by adding a `ResourceConfigurator` for it. This is mentioned briefly in the GitHub provider example in the upjet [docs](https://github.com/upbound/upjet/blob/main/docs/generating-a-provider.md?plain=1#L127).

```bash
   cat <<EOF > config/repository/config.go
   package repository

   import "github.com/upbound/upjet/pkg/config"

   // Configure configures individual resources by adding custom ResourceConfigurators.
   func Configure(p *config.Provider) {
       p.AddResourceConfigurator("github_repository", func(r *config.Resource) {
           // We need to override the default group that upjet generated for
           // this resource, which would be "github"
           r.ShortGroup = "repository"
       })
   }
   EOF
```

For a more significant example of customization, have a look at provider-aws, which uses a [custom mapping and trimming function](https://github.com/upbound/provider-aws/blob/main/config/groups.go#L39) to map from certain terraform resource names into specific Groups and Kinds.

```golang
// GroupKindOverrides overrides the group and kind of the resource if it matches
// any entry in the GroupMap.
func GroupKindOverrides() config.ResourceOption {
    return func(r *config.Resource) {
        if f, ok := GroupMap[r.Name]; ok {
            r.ShortGroup, r.Kind = f(r.Name)
        }
    }
}

// KindOverrides overrides the kind of the resources given in KindMap.
func KindOverrides() config.ResourceOption {
    return func(r *config.Resource) {
        if k, ok := KindMap[r.Name]; ok {
            r.Kind = k
        }
    }
}
```

This is then added into [config/provider.go](https://github.com/upbound/provider-aws/blob/main/config/provider.go#L138) to customize the behavior of the generator.

```golang
// GetProvider returns provider configuration
func GetProvider() *config.Provider {
    modulePath := "github.com/upbound/provider-aws"
    pc := config.NewProvider([]byte(providerSchema), "aws",
        modulePath, providerMetadata,
        config.WithShortName("aws"),
        config.WithRootGroup("aws.upbound.io"),
...
        config.WithDefaultResourceOptions(
            GroupKindOverrides(),
            KindOverrides(),        
...
        ),
        config.WithMainTemplate(hack.MainTemplate),
    )
...
```